# how to put TextViews next to each other

Tags: android, layout, textview

I want to create some TextViews and put them next to each other and if TextViews reached to end of page, it starts from below of previous TextViews. I wrote code for putting TextViews next to each other as below:

```
RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setText("Text"+String.valueOf(i));
    text.setId(i);
    main.addView(text, params);
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, text.getId());
}
```

but when TextViews reaches end of screen it be similar this:

[image: problem]

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most elegant way to do it is to use a adapter view like RecyclerView. You can define max number of items in each row. It works like ListView but with more features. Read about it here:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html
http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html